# launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

when I go to get the "bluetoothCentrals" it is always returned "nil"

The purpose of this application is to ensure that a ble device is connected once when the application is started and that when the application is killed the connection remains active, so that when I go to press a button in the bluetooth device, the application is reopened to make an api call

- **AppDelegate**

```swift
internal func application(
   _ application: UIApplication, 
   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
   guard let options = launchOptions,
         let bluetoothCentrals = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.bluetoothCentrals] as? [String]
   else {
      return true
   }

   print(bluetoothCentrals) // return always nil
   return true
}
```

- **CentralManager**

```swift
centralManager = CBCentralManager(
   delegate: self, 
   queue: nil, 
   options:[CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "centralManager"]
)
```

- **Capabilities**
  [Capabilities ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ookw1.png)
- **Info.plist**
  [Info.plist ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heyEj.png)

Comment: How are you relaunching your app?  Is the system doing it in response to a `notify` or completion of a pending `connect` From your peripheral?

Comment: At this moment I read the notify correctly but I don't wake up the application in any way, also because I don't know how to do it...
I haven't found any examples and apple's docs don't help that much @Paulw11

Comment: You are expecting to see the option in `didFinishLaunching`; how are you launching the app when you expect to see this option?  This option will only be present when iOS relaunches your app in response to Bluetooth activity, not when you launch it from Xcode. If you are connected to the peripheral and have an active notify or if you have a pending `Connect` then ios will relaunch your app in the background if it has been jettisoned due to memory pressure and new data arrives or the connect completes.

Comment: [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) (although old) and [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3115-bluetooth-state-restoration-app-relaunch-rules) explain things pretty well